# How do I make a new partition with an OS, move what I need there from the old OS, and succesfully delete and expand that space to the new OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

This might be simple as heck, but I am typing from my ubuntu installation as I just tried the above and I ended up with two unusable windows 10 partitions.. I tried to use Partition Wizard and now I am here It is on the same HDD, I first deleted the old partition, and then tried to expand the new OS to the old one and now I get error screens when I try to boot those windows installations. Where did I go wrong, how can I do it properly?

OR BETTER YET, can I make the old partition function again, it says it's missing winloader.exe I think

Comment: Boot from your installation medium and fix your boot. You probably shot your windows bootloader. I don't understand what you're trying to do and a listing of your current partition table would be kind of nice. If you're on windows you could use `diskpart` or the Storage management (possibily take screenshot) on Linux you could use `fdisk` or a GUI tool like GParted.

Comment: I fixed it! Not sure how I am going to go about removing the other partition and adding it to this one, but I fixed it! I can boot into where I want now. Thank you.